Error on load zip file with apache flink app "No valid JAR file found in the zip file."
I'm creating flink managed app with the code of the getting started from https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-managed-service-for-apache-flink-examples/tree/main/python/GettingStarted
I'm using pipeline to deploy the app, and create the zip the is uploaded to the bucket that is configure on the app. When i try to apply using the terraform i recevie the following error.
Error: creating Kinesis Analytics v2 Application (example-flink-application): operation error Kinesis Analytics V2: CreateApplication, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: f9e24c0a-8a7c-4da1-8a83-bd0c82cdad53, InvalidArgumentException: No valid JAR file found in the zip file.

The terraform wants to apply the following, that is correct about the artifact, bucket and key
 erraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # module.flink_app.aws_kinesisanalyticsv2_application.example will be created
  + resource "aws_kinesisanalyticsv2_application" "example" {
      + application_mode       = (known after apply)
      + arn                    = (known after apply)
      + create_timestamp       = (known after apply)
      + id                     = (known after apply)
      + last_update_timestamp  = (known after apply)
      + name                   = "example-flink-application"
      + runtime_environment    = "FLINK-1_8"
      + service_execution_role = "arn:aws:iam::991936303820:role/kinesis_analytics_role"
      + status                 = (known after apply)
      + tags                   = {
          + "Environment" = "test"
        }
      + tags_all               = {
          + "Environment" = "test"
        }
      + version_id             = (known after apply)

      + application_configuration {
          + application_code_configuration {
              + code_content_type = "ZIPFILE"

              + code_content {
                  + s3_content_location {
                      + bucket_arn = "arn:aws:s3:::my-flink-app-artifacts"
                      + file_key   = "artifacts/flink_app.zip"
                    }
                }
            }
          + environment_properties {
              + property_group {
                  + property_group_id = "InputStream0"
                  + property_map      = {
                      + "aws.region"           = "us-west-1"
                      + "flink.stream.initpos" = "LATEST"
                      + "stream.name"          = "InputStream0"
                    }
                }
              + property_group {
                  + property_group_id = "OutputStream0"
                  + property_map      = {
                      + "aws.region"  = "us-west-1"
                      + "stream.name" = "ExampleOutputStream"
                    }
                }
              + property_group {
                  + property_group_id = "kinesis.analytics.flink.run.options"
                  + property_map      = {
                      + "jar-file" = "lib/pyflink-dependencies.jar"
                      + "python"   = "flink_app.py"
                    }
                }
            }
          + flink_application_configuration {
              + checkpoint_configuration {
                  + checkpoint_interval           = (known after apply)
                  + checkpointing_enabled         = (known after apply)
                  + configuration_type            = "DEFAULT"
                  + min_pause_between_checkpoints = (known after apply)
                }
              + monitoring_configuration {
                  + configuration_type = "CUSTOM"
                  + log_level          = "DEBUG"
                  + metrics_level      = "TASK"
                }
              + parallelism_configuration {
                  + auto_scaling_enabled = true
                  + configuration_type   = "CUSTOM"
                  + parallelism          = 10
                  + parallelism_per_kpu  = 4
                }
            }
        }
    }

Could someone experimented something like this? my jar file is 56Mb and don't know why could be failing.
attached the zip file to let you know check it.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rOmI3xb5pvaLvzJQIGtzzLnQvDAE9JHb/view?usp=sharing
I've tried to change the location of the jar file inside the zip, but this seems not working.
